# Command line option and skip page

Tags: command-line, installation, command-line-arguments, nsis

I am creating a setup using NSIS which include some builtin pages and some custom page also.In that i want to show a custom page using install only if a command line is passed during install.How it can be done?

Example

```
!include "MUI.nsh"
!include nsDialogs.nsh

OutFile "myCustomPage.exe"
var installmethod
Page Custom MyCustomPage 
Page Custom MyCustomPage1 
Page Custom MyCustomPage3

Function MyCustomPage
 nsDialogs::Create 1044

     nsDialogs::Show

FunctionEnd
Function MyCustomPage1
 nsDialogs::Create 1044

     nsDialogs::Show

FunctionEnd
Function MyCustomPage3
 nsDialogs::Create 1044

     nsDialogs::Show
FunctionEnd
Section Dummy
SectionEnd
```

In the above example i have 3 pages.I want to shown only two pages MyCustomPage and MyCustomPage3 during normal install. If a command line(specif command line) passed then all 3 pages should appear during installation.how it can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
!include FileFunc.nsh
!include LogicLib.nsh

Page Custom MyPageCreate

Function MyPageCreate
${GetParameters} $0
ClearErrors
${GetOptions} "$0" "/ShowSpecial"  $1
${If} ${Errors}
    Abort ; Skip page
${EndIf}
nsDialogs::Create 1044
nsDialogs::Show
FunctionEnd
```

Comment: Some explanation of how you're doing what you're doing would be helpful.

Comment: Hello Andres. Please check my answer below. You have used getoption etc. Is there any problem in my method? It works properly. But my method is efficient and proper one?

Comment: If you are never going to support other parameters and don't care about quotes then your version is OK...

Comment: I do use other command lines but not for skipping these pages. Also what if quotes are there? Can you please explain

Comment: ${GetParameters} just grabs the command line string, ${GetOptions} parses it looking for the substring you specify...

Answer (score 0):

Below code skips page MyCustomPage1 if the command line option is "a".

```
!include "MUI.nsh"
!include "FileFunc.nsh"
!include nsDialogs.nsh
!insertmacro GetParameters

OutFile "myCustomPage.exe"
var installmethod
Page Custom MyCustomPage 
Page Custom MyCustomPage1 
Page Custom MyCustomPage3

Function MyCustomPage
    nsDialogs::Create 1044
    nsDialogs::Show
FunctionEnd

Function MyCustomPage1
    ${GetParameters} $R0
    ${If} $R0 == 'a'
        abort
    ${EndIf}
    nsDialogs::Create 1044
    nsDialogs::Show
FunctionEnd

Function MyCustomPage3
    nsDialogs::Create 1044
    nsDialogs::Show
FunctionEnd

Section Dummy
SectionEnd
```